# How to interrupt animation when clicking?

Tags: easeljs

I'm starting to work with EaselJS, so I'm making a simple demo:

A circle jumps up when you click it and falls back down afterwards.
My problem: When I click the circle BEFORE it returns to begin position, it doesn't react. It only reacts after it's back to its begin position.

Share your ideas! :)

Comment: How are you animating your circle? If you are using a Tween, you will have to interrupt it, otherwise it will override any change you make while the tween is running.

Comment: @Lanny I'm using a Tween, indeed. My question is how to interrupt it?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `override` property on Tween.get(). This will clear any existing tweens on the object.

```
createjs.Tween.get(target, {override:true}).to(...);
```